# trying to store all objects into one object with parse and jquery

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I'm trying to store all returned objects into one object for later use. I have the loop set in place but when I try to execute some code with the new object, its empty. In this case here alert the object. I guess the alert is executing before the loop is complete. Any way to fix this?

```
var followers = new Array;
Parse.initialize("xxxxxx", "xxxxx");
var currentUser = Parse.User.current();
var users = JSON.stringify(currentUser);
var user = eval("(" + users + ")");
var listsfollow = user.Follow;
for (var i = 0; i < listsfollow.length; i++) {
    var allUsers = Parse.Object.extend("User");
    var query = new Parse.Query(allUsers);
    query.get(listsfollow[i], {
        success: function (results) {
            followers.push(results);
        },
        error: function (object, error) {
            // The object was not retrieved successfully.
            // error is a Parse.Error with an error code and description.
        }
    });
};
alert(followers);
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I couldn't figure out how to make it wait for the query but I used this to do something after the last loop iteration. Worked great.

```
          if((--remaining)==0)alert(followers);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are correct and the AJAX stuff in jquery is async, and so the `.get()` will happen after the alert. The quickest and dirtiest way would be to set it to an async to false before issue the request: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/
A better way would be to have your code respond to the result of the call whenever it is ready. This will prevent page blocking and make your code faster.

Answer (score 0):

This is an asynchronous query, and the alert is being shown right after the query has initiated, so it's unlikely that it will be executed after the query has returned any results.

Any code that depends on the query's results should be moved into either the success or error callback functions.

Comment: Thanks Hector! Any examples? When I put my code inside the success it gets repeated during every iteration of the loop.

Comment: This should help: http://blog.parse.com/2013/01/29/whats-so-great-about-javascript-promises/